# How to avoid typing the container id when using docker commit?

Tags: docker, docker-image

Creating a new docker image from a container is done with the following syntax:

```
    $ docker commit -m "commit message" -a "author" \ 
      #containerid user/imagename:tag
```

I know you can get the last container id from:

```
    $ docker ps -l
```

But that gives me verbose output. How can I regex the container id or input a command to extract just the last container id so that I don't have to manually type it into my commit message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer and thought I'd post it in case someone else runs into the same issue:

```
$ sudo docker commit -m "commit message" -a "author" \ 
  $(sudo docker ps -lq) user/imagename:tag
```

You use docker ps -lq